# Why wont my code work to open a new file using sprintf and fopen?

Tags: c, printf, fopen, fwrite, fread

```
int main()
{
    int size = 512, i = 1;
    char buffer[1000];
    char *newFileTemp;
    char const *chunk = "Chunk";
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    FILE *fb;
    FILE *fp=fopen("blah.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("doesnt exist");
        return 0;
    }

     fread(buffer,sizeof(char),sizeof(buffer), fp);
     sprintf(newFileTemp, "%s%i", chunk, i);

     printf("blah check %s",newFileTemp);
     fb = fopen(newFileTemp, "wb");
     if (fb == NULL)
     {
         perror("doesnt exist");
         return 0;
     }
     fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), fb);

     fclose(fp);
     fclose(fb);

     return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use sprintf to create a new file named chunk1 that has the data of file blah.text (blah.txt is already created). But even though the code compiles properly, it doesn't create a new file. Please help.

Comment: It would be fantastic if you explained what it does do.

Comment: Please use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`.  (In this case, it might have pointed out that you had no buffer size to give it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is called an [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), because you are using `newFileTemp` before you have initialized it. To correct the problem, initialize it like this:

```
newFileTemp = (char*)malloc(100);
```

or declare it like this:

```
char newFileTemp[100];
```

The reason is that `sprintf` expects `newFileTemp` to have  enough space allocated for storing the string it is formatting (it will not allocate it for you).

## Also:

- If you use `malloc` don't forget to `free`.
- Don't forget to check the success of functions like [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) and [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/).
- You'll have another problem later because in your call to `fwrite` you are trying to write always 1000 bytes (`sizeof(buffer)` is 1000 bytes), even if your file had fewer bytes. This is where the return value of `fread` comes into play (it returns the actual amount of bytes read): you need to use that return value instead of `sizeof(buffer)`.

Comment: This is C: no `new`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice he had tagged it as C. Fixed.

Comment: I have to agree with this in a strict sense, but by leading with the undefined behavior angle it seems to bury the key point, which is that `sprintf()` doesn't just require its first argument to be a `char *`, but requires it to be a pointer [in]to an existing array of `char` large enough to receive the data that is "printed".  `sprintf()` not only *does not* allocate space and assign it to the pointer, it *cannot*.